# create new column for every day (from a single time series) in python

Tags: python, time-series, panel

Just wanted to know  how to create new columns for every day from a single time series in python so i will have 1440 rows and x column

my data looks like :

2020-12-22 21:37:00     1.21658
2020-12-22 21:38:00     1.21654
2020-12-22 21:39:00     1.21652
2020-12-22 21:40:00     1.21650
2020-12-22 21:42:00     1.21650
2020-12-22 21:43:00     1.21645
2020-12-22 21:44:00     1.21648
2020-12-22 21:45:00     1.21644

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate on the *days list*.

Assuming **df** is your pandas data frame:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

days = ['2020-12-22 21:37:00 1.21658', '2020-12-22 21:38:00 1.21654', '2020-12-22 21:39:00 1.21652', '2020-12-22 21:40:00 1.21650', '2020-12-22 21:42:00 1.21650', '2020-12-22 21:43:00 1.21645', '2020-12-22 21:44:00 1.21648', '2020-12-22 21:45:00 1.21644']


for day in days:
    df[str(day)] = np.nan
```

After that, you can populate your **rows** on each column.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({"A": [1,2,3], "B": [2,3,4]})

>>> print(df)
   A  B
0  1  2
1  2  3
2  3  4

df["C"] = "" # creating empty column

df["D"] = np.nan # creating nan values column

>>> print(df)
   A  B C   D
0  1  2   NaN
1  2  3   NaN
2  3  4   NaN
```